# Need help in creating a Kendo UI popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I need help creating this below UI (click on "Ui mock up" link) as a popup when clicking on a link. And each text (Text1, Text 2 and Text 3) would be a hyper link

We are using Kendo UI with ASP.Net MVC framework.

[UI mock up](http://i1372.photobucket.com/albums/ag328/giriragav/Untitled_zps8c8ada34.png)

Please lhelp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**View:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("popup")
    .Title("Whatever")
    .Content(@<text>
         anything you want here: the HTML for your 3 text links, for example
    </text>)
    .Modal(true)
    .Visible(false)
    .Width(200)
)
```

**Script:**

```
$("#popup").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
```

Call the script when clicking the link you want to trigger the popup.

Comment: I am more concerened about the outline of each box. Out lines are in ">" shape. Not sure how to implement that.

Comment: That's a whole different question. One thing is to display a popup, another is to design the HTML in it. Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rm9cc4e2/) - here's something similar to what you want